# why dart doesn't execute the code in order?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, dart-async

My Flutter app is executing the code inside the .then() function after everything is finished. I thought that this function was used to wait for the code to be executed. Am I understanding something wrong about dart?

This is my code:

```
static Future<List<Quiz>> getUserQuizzes(
      {FirebaseFirestore? firestore}) async {
    if (firestore == null) {
      firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    }

    List<Quiz> quizzes = [];

    /// Get the the id's of all quizzes whose creatorID is the current user's id
    await firestore
        .collection('quizzes')
        .where('creatorID', isEqualTo: getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      print('print 1: ${querySnapshot.docs.length}');

      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) async {
        print('print inside forEach');
        Quiz? tempQuiz;

        await Quiz().retrieveQuizFromId(id: doc.id).then((value) {
          tempQuiz = value;
          quizzes.add(tempQuiz!);
          print('print inside then: ${quizzes.length}');
        });
      });
    });

    print('print 2: ${quizzes.length}');
    return quizzes;
  }
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device iPhone 14 Pro Max...
Reloaded 1 of 1330 libraries in 385ms (compile: 61 ms, reload: 147 ms, reassemble: 128 ms).
flutter: print 1: 5
flutter: print inside forEach
flutter: print inside forEach
flutter: print inside forEach
flutter: print inside forEach
flutter: print inside forEach
flutter: print 2: 0
flutter: print inside then: 1
flutter: print inside then: 2
flutter: print inside then: 3
flutter: print inside then: 4
flutter: print inside then: 5
```